# Qt Creator and QML Live Preview

Tags: qt, qml

The problem now is that I don't know how I can use qml live preview?
I saw a video:
https://vimeo.com/145921618

I saw [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/35366) post about erase this function for Qt Creator.
How i can implementlive coding into my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [Terrarium](http://www.terrariumapp.com/)?

> Terrarium is a cross platform QML Playground: the view renders lively
>   as you type in the editor, makes prototyping and experimenting with
>   QtQuick a lot more fun!
>
> It monitors changes in its TextEdit, and triggers the view to reload
>   source from the local http server. If you're looking for a file system
>   watcher implementation, please refer to QML LiveReload.

Or [LiveReload](https://github.com/penk/qml-livereload)?

Comment: LiveReload, that's what i need. Thank you Sleeper.

Comment: both do not work on Mac with Mojave as per my tests

Answer (score 3):

As is evident from the video, this is as simple as auto reloading a QML file each time a chance to the file has been saved.

You can easily do that yourself, set up a `QFileSystemWatcher` and every time the file is modified, load the file in a QML view. And there you have it.

Of course, this is only good for previewing standalone components which can work on their own. You could go further, set the file system watcher to monitor the entire QML project and reload the main QML file every time something changes. It is a two step process, you need to monitor the directory, which only reflects adding or removing of files, and you subsequently add or remove those files from watching for changes.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of it, I want to share another tool that I found online.

It is a web based QML editor that gives immediate preview while writing the code. It has its limits, but still it's pretty useful for live QML coding

https://qmlweb.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested, in my Qt 5.10 installation, there is  a *qmlscene.exe* in bin folder (same location as qmake or assistant). Running on command line is fine, however it is not in Qt creator.

PS: I found this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qmlscene.html